# Bigquery Active User count not accurate (Google Analytics)

Tags: sql, database, google-analytics, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have Google Analytics integrated to Bigquery and I'm trying to write a query to fetch Active Users that should match with the number on GA Portal.

Here's the query I've written;

```
SELECT 
date(date) as date,
EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(fullVisitorId) as daily_active_users,
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([<project_id>:<dataset>.ga_sessions_],
TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01'),
TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()))
group by date
order by date desc
```

The numbers I get in response are somehow related to the ones Google Analytics shows me, but they aren't a 100% accurate.

The numebers I get in return are slightely higher than the ones on the portal and I assume I need to put a where clause to filter a property GA might be filtering on the portal.

Comment: Your query looks fine to me. Assuming that you're looking at the same GA view as the one linked to BigQuery, I think that the problem could be sampling. Have you checked that there is no sampling in your GA report? Even if the GA UI says that "This report is based on 100% of sessions.", try to export it as an Unsampled Report and check the numbers (in my experience, the users metric sometimes doesn't match between unsampled reports and default reports without sampling).

Comment: @PolFerrando Thankyou very much man!!!! I was banging my head over this for days! wow! You're a life saver!

Comment: @PolFerrando Please write your comment as an answer so I can accept it! I'm so sure a lot of other devs are banging their heads like me too.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Just wrote the comment as an answer.

Comment: @PolFerrando I was implementing Google Search Analytics and I see the same number discrepancy in it as well. Do you think it could be the same reason? The thing is, in Google Analytics I could still pull an unsampled report and verify the numbers, I don't have the same feature in Google Search Console.
Just wanted to see if you've had similar experience in that as well

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Google Search data...

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the support! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query looks fine to me. Assuming that you're looking at the same GA view as the one linked to BigQuery, I think that the problem could be sampling.

Even if the GA UI says that "This report is based on 100% of sessions.", try to export it as an Unsampled Report and check the numbers (in my experience, the users metric sometimes doesn't match between unsampled reports and default reports without sampling).